# Reload bean in all the running instances of service

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, microservices, spring-bean

I have created an endpoint for reloading bean and it's working as expected calling from API Gateway. Now the problem is, that there are 2 instances running of my service. Bean is reloading in only one instance. How can I reload bean in all the running instances?

Comment: I can think of several potential ways to solve this need; choosing the most appropriate one depends on a lot of context of the situation (architecture, available infrastructure, available time, tolerance for failure, just to name a few). It's not a great question for providing concrete answers without some more context.

Comment: how can we reload bean in all the running instances?

Comment: Please read [ask].